# Face will only extrude on z axis. What did I do?

Tags: modeling

I am doing the donut tutorial and am trying to extrude a face to begin making my cup handle.  But whenever I hit <kbd>E</kbd>  it only extrudes on the Z axis.

Since I started doing it before and it was working but I shut down to do something else, now it won't work.

Comment: Press z again may have to do it more than once.

Comment: Ok this is hilarious.  I went back to do that and the problem was no longer there.  I guess blender got over it's snit.  Thanks anyway

Comment: If you extrude a face it will always be locked by normal axis of that face by default (quite likely in your case normal axis of that face was equal to global Z axis). If you extrude several edges without face shared between them extrusion won't be locked. That was probably the reason